# JSON Transform Only Returning 1st Item in JSON Object

Tags: node.js

I am using [object-mapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-mapper) to transform a JSON object to a different JSON format. The following works... but only produces the first entry in the JSON I have. Is there some sort of foreach or iteration that needs to be added?

This:

```
  var src = response.data;

  var map = {
    "value.segments.start": "value.start",
    "value.segments.end": "value.end",
    "value.segments.segments.performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage.avg": "value.cpu"
  };

  var dest = objectMapper(src, map);

  res.send(dest);
```

Produces this:

```
{
  "value": {
    "start": "2021-04-15T00:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2021-04-16T00:00:00.000Z",
    "cpu": 9.01
  }
}
```

But here is my response.data as I get JSON from one source and need to transform it to another format, as you can see multiple entries and I expected to multiple entries in the object-mapped output:

```
{
  "value": {
    "start": "2021-04-14T18:17:27.086Z",
    "end": "2021-04-15T18:17:27.086Z",
    "interval": "PT1H",
    "segments": [
      {
        "start": "2021-04-14T18:17:27.086Z",
        "end": "2021-04-14T19:00:00.000Z",
        "segments": [
          {
            "performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage": {
              "avg": 22.9
            },
            "customDimensions/Role": "CD"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "start": "2021-04-14T19:00:00.000Z",
        "end": "2021-04-14T20:00:00.000Z",
        "segments": [
          {
            "performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage": {
              "avg": 23.51
            },
            "customDimensions/Role": "CD"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "start": "2021-04-15T00:00:00.000Z",
        "end": "2021-04-15T01:00:00.000Z",
        "segments": [
          {
            "performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage": {
              "avg": 8.85
            },
            "customDimensions/Role": "CD"
          }
        ]
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `objectMapper` is just for Objects, not arrays of objects. You should have luck with the following:

```
  var src = response.data;

  var map = {
    "value.segments.start": "value.start",
    "value.segments.end": "value.end",
    "value.segments.segments.performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage.avg": "value.cpu"
  };

  var dest = src.map(s => objectMapper(s, map) );

  res.send(dest);
```

Comment: No such luck but like where you are heading with this. Do I need to declare "s" somewhere or is that just the same as stating "function(s)"?

Comment: Yep, these two functions are identical: `const fnName = s => s.id` and `function fnName(s) { return s.id}`. It's ES6 arrow function syntax with an implicit return

Comment: Thanks, I tried the call but it would not return. Wondering if I need to setup an empty array and append to it. Is there an option to achieve what I need without the library?

Comment: Yes, it looks like the library is just syntactical sugar for stuff you can do yourself relatively easily. I'll edit my answer with a simple example that you can extend.

Comment: I also read your response.data value too quickly. It *is* an object, not an array, so there is no `.map()` function on its prototype, and that's why it's not returning anything. Sorry about that... And looking even more closely, the solution will require recursion (calling a function from within the same function, depending on a condition) since similar objects are embedded within each other... Sorry but this is a little more than I can help with actually.

Comment: No worries! I am going to use the regular .map function and not use the library.

Comment: ... after I output this into an array so I can play with some of the values/formats